# Scara Robot Inverse Kinematics

Tags: c++, math, arduino, robotics

I am working on a Scara Robot controlled by an Arduino and trying to figure out the inverse kinematics. I programmed a simple example sketch to test my function but it doesn't work because of a mathematical error. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
const int L1 = 202.25;
const int L2 = 193.35;

int alpha = 0;
int beta = 0;

void calc_IK(int x, int y){
  beta = acos((x*x+y*y-L1*L1-L2*L2)/2*L1*L2); //I could also ise pow()
  alpha = atan((y/x)-atan(L2*sin(beta)/L1+L2*cos(beta)));
  Serial.println(alpha, beta);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  calc_IK(3, 5);
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: `const int L1 = 202.25;` Well, integers don't have decimal points, they are whole numbers. You probably want to use `double` instead.

Comment: the same goes for the angles `alfa,beta` and probably also coordiantes `x,y`... maybe `float` is enough as FPU is not a guarantee on arduino used MCUs ...

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work and I get NaN. I changed L1 and L2 to doubles and alpha, beta , x and y to float.

Comment: @Aterox its better to have all as float or all as double do not mix as that requires runtime conversions... where do you get `NaN` ?  with what values ? you know `acos(a)`  is working only if `|a| <= 1.0` , atan has some singularities and `y/x` should have nonzero `x` ... and also make sure you have correct units for angles  ... most libs/languages want `[rad]`  instead of `[deg]`...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the error was but I changed some variables to float and some to doubles. I also noticed that the result was in radians so I have to convert it to degrees. Here is my now functioning code:

```
#include <math.h>

const double L1 = 202.25;
const double L2 = 193.35;

float alpha = 0; //radians
float beta = 0;

float beta_d; //degrees
float alpha_d;

void calc_IK(float x, float y){
  beta = acos((pow(x, 2)+pow(y, 2)-pow(L1, 2)-pow(L2, 2))/(2*pow(L1, 2)*pow(L2, 2)));
  alpha = atan((y/x)-atan((L2*sin(beta))/(L1+L2*cos(beta))));

  beta_d = beta * 180/M_PI;
  alpha_d = alpha * 180/M_PI;


  Serial.print("Beta: ");
  Serial.print(beta_d);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("Alpha: "); 
  Serial.print(alpha_d);
  Serial.println(" ");

}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  calc_IK(3.0, 5.0);
}
```

It may not be the best but it works.

Comment: `pow(x, 2)` should be much much slower than `(x*x)` however do not forget the parenthis `()` as MCU compilers are usually the worst with operand priorities ... and I would have the `L1,L2` as `float` too I do not think you hitting its accuracy limits